# Disable XML validation when using XDocument

Tags: c#, .net, validation, linq-to-xml

I'm parsing an [XLIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XLIFF) document using the XDocument class. Does XDocument perform some validation of the content which I read into it, and if so - is there any way to disable that validation?

I'm getting some weird errors if the XLIFF isn't valid XML (I don't care that it isn't, I just want to parse it).

E.g.

```
'.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character.
```

I'm currently reading the file like this:

```
string FileLocation = @"C:\XLIFF\text.xlf";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FileLocation);
```

Thanks.

Comment: How do you load xml into XDocument? From file ? Can you show that line of code?

Comment: If it isn't valid, then it isn't XML. How could `XDocument` work with it?

Comment: @HABJAN - Yes I'm just loading the content from a file.

Comment: @Jimmy C: can i see that couple lines of code?

Comment: @habjan I've added the code I use to read the file.

Comment: @Jimmy C: did you try what i suggested you in my answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had similar problem which was fixed by letting StreamReader to read the content.

```
// this line throws exception like yours
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(@"C:\test.xml");

// works
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\test.xml"));
```

If that does not help, try to include proper encoding.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying this now.

Comment: This seems to have worked - can you explain to me why it works?

Comment: Because it seems that StreamReader auto detects encoding.

Comment: No. StreamReader defaults to UTF-8 as described in the [Remarks of its MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Going to try this out now with a few more language XLIFF files.

Comment: Ok, i took a look inside XDocument.Load method and i noticed that when you use filename as parameter then it uses XmlReader to read out the file. XmlReader uses XmlParserContext which is null when XmlReader is used from XDocument. XmlParserContext has Encoding propery which is also null as XmlParserContext is null. XmlReader uses that Encoding property to read out file content.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: Yep, but it also has detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks flag set to true.

Comment: I'm still seeing this error - it seemed to work the first time, but I see it again. How can I specify the encoding to use when I read the document?

Comment: XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\test.xml", Encoding.UTF8));

Comment: Thanks - what encoding would you recommed for file that will contain content from many languages (Spanish, French, German, Dutch etc.) ?

Comment: Try with Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250"); See other encodings: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252. Docs say that it's preferred to use UTF-8 or UTF-16.

Comment: @Jimmy: It really depends on the encoding the file is in!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to strip characters from strings that are invalid for use in XML, you can use this method:

```
private static string RemoveXmlInvalidCharacters(string s)
{
    return Regex.Replace(
        s,
        @"[^\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD\u10000-\u10FFFF]",
        string.Empty);
}
```

It removes any characters that fall outside of the set of valid character values, according to the XML standard.

Answer (score 2):

You can't parse invalid XML, because parsing requires a valid XML structure.
It might be the case that you read the file as ASCII when you should have read it as UTF-8 or UTF-16 and that leads to the problem you encountered.

**Possible solution:**
Read the file as UTF-8.

Comment: How does XDocument determine the encoding to use to read the file? Is there a default, and how can I change this to try UTF8 or UTF16?

Comment: @Jimmy: Please report back, if HABJAN's solution doesn't work.

Comment: will do. The file is still processing.

Answer (score 2):

XLIFF document **is** an XML document. Character 0x00 is **not a valid XML character**. Invalid XML is not an XML so you cannot read it using XML parsers.

Now well-formed is a different thing, you can use SAX parsers to read XML which is not well-formed but not Invalid XML.

Valid characters according to XML Specification:

```
 #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]
```

---

### UPDATE

Suggested solution: Pre-Process the files to remove invalid characters. Character `\0` can be replaced with space unless it has a meaning (is binary) in which case it needs to come in **Base64** format.

Comment: Please elaborate on the difference between "not well-formated" and "invalid".

Comment: Sorry it is well-formed, my mistake, fixed. Well-formed: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Well-formedness_and_error-handling

Comment: @Aliostad: I don't agree. The problem is nearly 100% certain an encoding problem, which is solved by reading the file with the proper encoding. \0 **IS** valid in an XML file, **IF** the file is encoded in UTF-16 or Unicode. To clarify: It is only invalid in the string that is passed to the XML parser.

Comment: @Daniel. It is likely but we have not seen the file so we are just guessing.

Comment: You are right, but I think your suggestion gives him wrong ideas :) He might just go with it and screw up his file...

Comment: @Aliostad: i had a same problem and i fixed it in way i described in my answer.