# Read and Remove invalid characters from xml outside xml elements in C# Linq to Xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am facing a problem while reading xml in C# linq to xml.

When I try to read xml document by using following statement:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path);
```

It throws an exception like this.

**Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.**

When I open the xml file that I was trying to read, I found an invalid character before xml declaration. Here is the declaration:

```
?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

I know the question mark at the start of declarations shouldn't be there.

I have three questions

**1)** How to read this invalid xml in C# linq to xml?

**2)** How to remove such kind of invalid characters any where in the xml in C#?

**3)** How to prevent these kind of invalid characters while creating the xml in c# linq to xml?

xml sample:      `?<?`

hex equivalent : `3f 3c 3f`

And here is the code that I am using to create it:

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
xdoc.Add(new XElement("TaskAlert"));
AddParentNodeInTaskAlertXml(ref xdoc, userId);
and so on......
```

I couldn't understand the reason why it add such kind of characters sometime.

Here is some code that I am using to create or load the file:

```
public static void CreateUpdateTaskAlertXmlFile(int userId)
        {
            try
            {
                string path = string.Format("{0}\\{1}\\{2}", Application.StartupPath, "Configuration",
                                            "TaskAlert.xml");
                if (userId.Equals(0))
                    userId = Utility.Application.CurrentUser.UserId;

                XDocument xdoc;
                LoadTaskAlertXml(out xdoc, path, userId);
                xdoc.Save(path);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                MSLib.HandleException(exception);
            }
        }

        public static void LoadTaskAlertXml(out XDocument xdoc, string path, int userId)
        {
            xdoc = null;
            TaskCollection tasks = TaskEntity.GetOverDueTasks(userId);
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                CreateTaskAlertXml(userId.ToString(), ref xdoc);
                AddOverDueTasksInTaskAlertXml(xdoc, userId.ToString(), tasks, false);
            }
            else
            {
                xdoc = XDocument.Load(path);

                XElement userElement =
                    xdoc.Descendants("User").Where(x => x.Attribute("Id").Value.Equals(userId.ToString())).
                        SingleOrDefault();

                if (userElement == null)
                {
                    AddParentNodeInTaskAlertXml(ref xdoc, userId.ToString());
                    AddOverDueTasksInTaskAlertXml(xdoc, userId.ToString(), tasks, false);
                }
                else
                    AddOverDueTasksInTaskAlertXml(xdoc, userId.ToString(), tasks, true);
            }
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable XML validation when using XDocument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497572/disable-xml-validation-when-using-xdocument)

Comment: @Naveed: As Jon already said, please provide us with the hex value of the first character.

Comment: hex value of first character is 3f

Comment: Is this a Unicode byte-order mark, then converted as unknown character back to ASCII encoding -- which then gets turned into "?"  This happens quite often when you're simplistically converting Unicode texts into ASCII format by converting each character.

Comment: Thanks Stephen Chung. I am simply creating the file using code that is mentioned in my post. I am not mentioning any encoding format while creating the file. By default it is created with utf-8 encoding.

Comment: @Naveed: Your code doesn't create any files. It creates an in-memory object. Please show the code to actually create the file.

Comment: Why are you using an out parameter for a method which has a void return type? Just make LoadTaskAlertXml return XDocument...

Answer (score 3):

LINQ to XML wouldn't *create* an invalid file to start with, so question 3 is moot.

LINQ to XML is only designed to *read* valid XML. You should find out why you've ended up with invalid XML to start with, and fix the root cause. It's generally a bad idea to try to fix an already-invalid file, especially without understanding the root cause to start with - you never know what other problems might be lurking round the corner.

I suspect that the extra character was *originally* a byte order mark, but that it's been mangled by something else. If you can give us more information about how you've created the file in the first place, that would help a lot. LINQ to XML can read files which start with a valid BOM with no problems.

I suggest you look at the file in a *binary* editor and edit your question with exactly the bytes at the start of the file. A valid UTF-8 BOM would be 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF.

EDIT: It sounds like the bug is in the way you're creating the file. For example, this should be absolutely fine:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        XDocument doc = new XDocument();
        doc.Add(new XElement("Test"));
        doc.Save("test.xml");
    }
}
```

That creates a file with a *valid* byte order mark. Please show an equivalent program which doesn't, or investigate exactly what you're doing with the file, e.g. copying via FTP.

As an aside, do you really need to use `ref` in your call to `AddParentNodeInTaskAlertXml`? It seems unlikely to me. See my [parameter passing article](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) if you're not quite sure what `ref` really means.

Comment: @Naveed: Please update your original question with your XML file. It will be more readable.

Comment: @Naveed: Posting XML into a comment isn't going to help. You should edit your question showing the *binary* data at the start of the file, as hex. It's the first character that's relevant, and we need to know what it's like at a binary level, not what your text editor shows it as.

Comment: hex value of first character is 3f.

Comment: @Naveed: In that case it's definitely *not* a valid BOM. How did the file get created in the first place?

Comment: @Naveed: You've shown the code you've used to create an XDocument, but not how you've then saved it. A short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem would be useful... are you by any chance explicitly using Encoding.ASCII anywhere?

Comment: I am saving the file using xdoc.Save(path); Not using any encoding while creating or updating the file. Thanx..

Comment: @Naveed: And is the file being copied anywhere somehow? I'm afraid I simply don't believe that LINQ to XML is creating an invalid file like that. Please show a *complete* program which generates an invalid file. It only needs a single element. I'll edit my answer to show what I mean.

Comment: It doesn't create the wrong xml first time. It is a very rare case. I am manipulating the xml file wile tasks are added, updated or snoozed. And it works perfectly. Some times only for some users, might be during updating, it added some invalid characters in the xml and then it starts throwing exceptions. I am simply saving the xml after updating it using the syntax xdoc.Save(path); This error is one of them that i have posted. This xml is send to us from our client today and i have seen this issue.

Comment: @Naveed: My guess is that your client has loaded the file in a text editor and then saved it as ASCII. Are you saying you can't actually reproduce this problem yourself? If so, it would really have been useful to say so to start with...

Comment: I am really unable to reproduce it. As i already mention that it is very rare. Well it is dynamically created always.

Comment: @Naveed: Well it certainly sounds to me like the file has been messed up outside LINQ to XML. I simply don't believe that LINQ to XML would create a broken BOM like that.

Comment: Thanks Jon for your participation. Let me sort out the problem and will update here if  i am able to fix it. Thank you so much once again..

Comment: I am having this same issue... some xml files have invalid characters and some files(majority) are okay... all files are created by the same application

Comment: @iroegbu: I suggest you ask a new question with more details. My guess is that you're applying an incorrect encoding, but we need more information, and the comments of this question aren't the best place to give that information.

Comment: sorry, I've fixed it though... File was corrupted during transfer. Thanks.